# When to set Lightning access=GLOBAL in Managed Packages

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package, isv

Reading the latest [Lightning Components Developer Guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/lightning.pdf) I couldn't find out where and where not to use `access=GLOBAL` in Lightning Components that I want to package in a managed app. I'm confused about the following questions:

1. I know that `<aura:component>`s that should show up in the **App Builder** need to be GLOBAL. What about the **internal sub-components** that are used by them?
2. What about the `<aura:attribute>`s? Do only need those to be GLOBAL that are exposed to the App Builder via a `.design` file?
3. When can I make `<aura:attribute>` `access=private`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's consider the following base scenario to answer your questions:

- you plan to use a `contrib:parentComp` component.
- `contrib:parentComp` has a child component `contrib:childComp`.
- `contrib:childComp` has 3 attributes `globalAttr`, `publicAttr` and `privateAttr` with the 'hinted' access levels.
- the `contrib` namespace does not belong to your org.
- your org has your own `myns` customized namespace (it could also be the default `c` namespace as long as it differs from `contrib`).

Back to your questions, here are the answers:

1. Only the `parentComp` component needs to be `global` if your want to use it in the `myns` namespace.

   - If `childComp` is `public` you cannot directly call it as a standalone in your `myns` code but `parentComp` will still work as expected.
   - If `childComp` is `global` you could call it directly in your `myns` code without using `parentComp`.
2. The same rule applies to `aura:attribute`. Let's consider for this answer that `childComp` is `global`.

   - If you use it in `myns` code, you can only access `globalAttr`.
   - If you use it in `contrib` code (in the org where the component was implemented) then, you can access `globalAttr` and `publicAttr` when declaring an instance of the component.
3. `private` attributes are used to hold internal component state that will not be shared with a parent component regardless of the namespace.

I hope that this clarifies the use of the different access levels.

Answer (score 5):

The Developer's Blog on [How to Design, Build and Publish Your Lightning Component for AppExchange](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/03/design-build-publish-lighting-component-appexchange.html) states the following:

> Development best practice is to specify access attributes manually
>   from the start. If you are planning to contribute an application or
>   component, remember to always use “global” access to expose
>   functionalities.

For point number 1, as a best practice, always set component level access to GLOBAL if you wish to expose them.

For point 2, if you plan on making the attributes accessible through the .design file, you will need to set access to GLOBAL.

For point 3, It is recommended to set them to private if you don't plan on making them accessible by other components outside of the attribute’s namespace.

As mentioned in [Attribute Access control](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/access_attr.htm) and  in [Modularizing Code in Lightning Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/12/lightning-components-code-sharing.html)

Both articles are worth reading.

Generally speaking:

- Global: Any component can access the value of this attribute.
- Public: Only components in the same namespace can set the value of
  this attribute.
- Private: Only this component can set the value of this attribute.

Comment: I could accept this as answer if you add a solution to 1) 2) and 3) and point to resources.

Comment: @glls I disagree with Point 1. Only add `access="global"` to component which are going to be exposed to subscribers.

Comment: point 1 is in context of the documentation," need to be global if you wish to expose them". I should specify it to avoid confusion. Thanks @Praveen for pointing that out